# How to make a list of datetimes with a distance-like constraint?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My inputs are :

1. Two datetimes and a range :

   ```
   start_dt = datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 26, 6, 0, 0)
   end_dt = datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 26, 15, 0, 0)
   range_of_minutes = range(15, 201) # between 15 and 200 minutes
   ```
2. A pandas DataFrame :

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(
       {'item':
        ['XXX01', 'XXX02', 'XXX03', 'XXX04',
         'XXX05', 'XXX06', 'XXX07', 'XXX08', 'XXX09']}
   )
   ```

And I'm trying to create a single column `datetime` with the following logic :

> For each consecutive item (starting from the second), generate a datetime between `start_dt` and `end_dt`. The interval of minutes should be random and should respect `range_of_minutes`. The items are unique by the way and could be of any number (odd or even).

The expected output would look like below (the first two columns only) :

```
    item             datetime **datetimes are monotonic and range is respected**
0  XXX01  26/07/2023 06:00:00                           NaN
1  XXX02  26/07/2023 06:17:34                         15,52
2  XXX03  26/07/2023 06:53:55                         36,35
3  XXX04  26/07/2023 08:05:15                         71,33
4  XXX05  26/07/2023 09:54:10                        108,92
5  XXX06  26/07/2023 11:08:20                         74,17
6  XXX07  26/07/2023 11:30:20                            22
7  XXX08  26/07/2023 14:07:05                        156,75
8  XXX09  26/07/2023 14:45:08                         38,05
```

My desperate attempt :

```
import random

def r_interval():
    return random.randint(min(range_of_minutes), max(range_of_minutes))

df.loc[0, "datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(start_dt)

df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(start_dt) + [r_interval() + dt.shift() for dt in df["datetime"][1:]]
```

Any help would be greately appreciated guys.

Comment: Should the datetime column be ordered or is it actually random? Also why are all the dates the same if they should be anywhere between `start_dt` and `end_dt`?

Comment: 1) The datetime column should start from `start_dt` and the rest of datetimes should be monotonic. 2) If you mean by the dates `DDMMYYYY`, yes they are the same because `start_dt` and `end_dt` have the same date.

Comment: Understood. You can just generate a sorted array of random minutes and use that to get the desired column. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a super straightforward approach, borderline with stupid, but if you don't have a lot of data to process, it works well and gives honest random result and is easy to code.
On the other hand with more data it will be slow.

If I understood correctly, the problem is to squeeze time intervals so that they still were random, but in certain borders all together.

My suggestion is to generate random intervals, check if they fit into the large interval and if not - generate again and again.

```
%%time

import numpy as np
import random

def r_interval():
    return random.randint(min(range_of_minutes), max(range_of_minutes))

def get_time_intervals(length, max_diff):
    attempt = 0
    while True:
        intervals = np.cumsum([0] + [r_interval() for _ in range(length - 1)])
        if intervals[-1] - intervals[0] <= max_diff:
            return intervals, attempt + 1
        attempt += 1

intervals, number_of_attempts = get_time_intervals(
    df.shape[0],
    int((end_dt - start_dt).seconds / 60)
)
df["datetime"] = [start_dt + datetime.timedelta(0, int(interval) * 60) for interval in intervals]

print(f"number of attempts: {number_of_attempts}")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
number of attempts: 16
    item            datetime
0  XXX01 2023-07-26 06:00:00
1  XXX02 2023-07-26 06:36:00
2  XXX03 2023-07-26 07:48:00
3  XXX04 2023-07-26 08:37:00
4  XXX05 2023-07-26 11:53:00
5  XXX06 2023-07-26 12:35:00
6  XXX07 2023-07-26 13:06:00
7  XXX08 2023-07-26 13:40:00
8  XXX09 2023-07-26 14:00:00
CPU times: user 6.34 ms, sys: 1.78 ms, total: 8.12 ms
Wall time: 8.89 ms
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your approach gives me what I need. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Create the column at once with list comprehension:

```
offsets = [0]+sorted(random.randint(min(range_of_minutes), max(range_of_minutes)) for _ in range(df.shape[0]-1))
df["datetime"] = [pd.to_datetime(start_dt)+pd.DateOffset(minutes=o) for o in offsets]

>>> df
    item            datetime
0  XXX01 2023-07-26 06:00:00
1  XXX02 2023-07-26 06:23:00
2  XXX03 2023-07-26 07:36:00
3  XXX04 2023-07-26 07:57:00
4  XXX05 2023-07-26 07:59:00
5  XXX06 2023-07-26 08:37:00
6  XXX07 2023-07-26 09:01:00
7  XXX08 2023-07-26 09:11:00
8  XXX09 2023-07-26 09:19:00
```